# how to select mysql row with mutliple values match

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a mysql table of a product with more than 6 services added on it(column).

Those column you can consider as `service1, service2, service3, service4, service5, service6`

Now I am displaying the data table on a page. To filter that table accordingly services i am using a form including check boxes for each service.

each check box is having a `value = "Yes"`

Now when i select the services and press the submit button it will refresh the page with passing query parameter like this

```
page.php?service1=Yes&service2=Yes&service3=&service4=&service5=Yes&service6=
```

here those services are blank that means i didn't select from the form so they come blank here. If i select them it will come Yes value on it.

I want to select the table rows with services are having "Yes" values. and ignore those values which are no values.

how to do?

Comment: This is pretty simple with a WHERE clause. Did you tried something?

Comment: Please try to solve your problem yourself before asking here. If you come to a point where you can't progress because you do not understand where the problem is, then ask. but that means you can ask a specific question, not something like "how can I program something"...

Comment: yes but if there will be no value on query parameter i want to ignore that. like if service1 = Yes and service2 is not = yes or blank it will not put on WHERE clause

Comment: You are answering your own question. `if` a service is not needed, then you will not add it to the where clause.

Comment: Are we talking about user-HTML element interaction? Or are we talking about what you should do in page.php for unchecked checkboxes? And how is this mysql related? Your question is a bit vague, please elaborate.

Comment: enenen no no you didn't understand, how do i program it if service1 is Yes, service2 is blank, service3 is blank, service 4 is Yes 
or sometimes vice versa. The parameters will pass accordingly the form values if i select the service then only it will come Yes on the service. so i want to match only those service which are having "Yes values" the blank one should be ingnored

Comment: @utkuerd - I am using a form with 6 checkboxes to filter my mysql table displaying on the same page. the mysql table is having column service1, service2, service3, service4, service5 and service6.
Now when i submit the form by cheking 1-2 service its pass the query on url like i mentioned on the question
page.php?service1=Yes&service2=Yes&service3=&service4=&service5=Yes&service6=

i want to select only those service which are having Yes values to match the values with WHERE clause on my mysql query to filter that.
now u get it what i am trying to do?

Comment: i tried something likw this to create a query but didn't worked

`code`    $query_fields = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE ".if($_REQUEST['service1']!=""){."`service1`='Yes'". };
        $query_fields +=  if($_REQUEST['service2']!=""){." and `service2`='Yes' ".};
        $query_fields += " ORDER BY `id` DESC";

Comment: @HarishKumar, I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing an answer but please try to make some effort before asking next time:

**HTML:**

```
<form name="form" method="get" action="">
    Service 1: <input type="checkbox" name="service1"/><br/>
    Service 2: <input type="checkbox" name="service2"/><br/>
    Service 3: <input type="checkbox" name="service3"/><br/>
    Service 4: <input type="checkbox" name="service4"/><br/>
    Service 5: <input type="checkbox" name="service5"/><br/>
    Service 6: <input type="checkbox" name="service6"/><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])) { // If the form is submitted
    $services = array(); // Define an empty array

    for($i = 1; $i<=6; $i++) {
        if($_GET["service$i"]) { // If Service(x) checkbox is checked
            $services[] = "service$i = 'Yes'"; // Add to array
        }
    }

    if(count($services) > 0) {
        print_r($services); // Here are all choosed services

        $selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $services) . ";";
        // Take a look what implode function does: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

        echo $selectQuery; // Now fetch the result using this query
    } else {
        // There is not any service checked. Maybe you can just get all the information from the table in this case.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to check that you want to check some fields to be blank, and some to be 'Yes'?

If so something like this:-

```
<?php

$RequiredVars = array('service1'=>'Yes','service2'=>'Yes','service3'=>'Yes','service4'=>'Yes','service5'=>'Yes','service6'=>'Yes');

$Clause = array();
foreach($_REQUEST AS $Field=>$Value)
{
    if (array_key_exists($Field, $RequiredVars))
    {
        $Clause[] = " $Field = '".mysql_real_escape_string($Value)."' ";
    }
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM SomeTable ";

if (count($Clause) > 0)
{
    $sql .= "WHERE ".implode(' AND ', $Clause);
}

?>
```